# Need help to locate an element using css selector

Tags: css-selectors

Currently I am trying following code, it returns 6 < th > elements (as picture pasted below). I need to get the last < th > element. I think I need to use ":last-child" here, but can't figure out what is the correct syntax to do it.

```
    "#viewsamples-grid thead th:not([style])[data-title]"
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try `#viewsamples-grid thead th:not([style]):last-child[data-title]`?

Comment: @Hybrid tied, it is illegal syntax syntax

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the last element in a set of matched elements within a CSS selector. You will need to locate all the elements and get the last one separately in code.